# Cannot access port on host mapped to docker container port

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have started a docker container using the command

```
sudo docker run -it -P -d plcdimage
```

The image is built using a Dockerfile which has instruction EXPOSE 8080. Container runs a jboss server with an application deployed on it. Port mappings are :

```
Command: sudo docker port be1837e849dc

Output: 8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32771
```

When I try to access the web application running on jboss in the container from the mapped host port using url:

http://IPAddressOfHost:32771/

I get connection refused error. Following is the result of command "netstat -tulpn"

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::9999                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::32771                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

I tried doing telnet hostip 32771 and it also results in connection refused.

```
Docker version 1.12.1  
build 23cf638
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First thing to check is if your container is actually listening on port 8080. You can get the IP address of your container with `docker inspect`, and try browsing from the host to `http://[container-ip]:8080`

Comment: What is the result of `sudo docker ps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that jboss server running inside the container was not listening on 0.0.0.0. One option to do this is, while starting the standalone server use -b 0.0.0.0.

/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0